# How fgets treats \n?

Tags: c, string, fgets

I have written the below code to sort strings in alphabetical order.But I m unable to understand how `fgets` is working here.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char s[10][15];
    int n;
    printf("enter the no of names\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       fgets(s[i],15,stdin);
       //scanf("%s",s[i]);
    }
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n-i;j++)
            if(strcmp(s[j],s[j+1])>0)
        {
            char g[15];
            strcpy(g,s[j]);
            strcpy(s[j],s[j+1]);
            strcpy(s[j+1],g);
        }
    }
    printf("the sorted strings are");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%s",s[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

If I use `scanf` instead of `fgets` to accept strings, `n` words are accepted but when I'm using `fgets` for same purpose instead of `scanf`, `n-1` words are accepted. Why is it so?

Is `fgets` placing last newline character in the `n`th place?

Comment: What length are the strings you are entering? Does it make a difference if you replace `15` with `100` everywhere? Is there an "empty" string in a redirected file (`scanf` ignores whitespace)? Also please see [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221)

Comment: @WeatherVane I m not entering more than 14 characters and how does that matter here?

Comment: Just make the string lengths 100 and remove all doubt. `fgets` retains the newline, perhaps you are not counting the extra **two** elements needed for newline and nul terminator. @dbush answer is good, but your string lengths are still too short for 14 chacacters.

Comment: The `scanf()` leaves an "empty" `\n` in the buffer. That "empty" `\n` gets read in the first `fgets()` call. Don't mix `scanf()` and `fgets()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Only null terminator gets added right?Because newline stays in buffer.

Comment: Nope, `fgets` reads the newline. Please don't be mean with buffer sizes.

Comment: As an aside, why are you prompting for the number of inputs?  Read the data one line at a time until there's no more data.  Doing so is more idiomatic and less error prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what happens when you mix `fgets` and `scanf` calls in the same program.

You start out using `scanf` to read the number of names.  This reads a number and leaves a newline in the input buffer.  When you then go into your loop and call `fgets` for the first time it reads that newline in the buffer immediately and then goes to the next iteration of the loop, calling `fgets` again.

When you use `scanf` in the loop instead, the `%s` format specifier first reads and discards and whitespace characters, which includes the newline from the prior `scanf` call.

If you still want to use `fgets`, you first need to clear the input buffer prior to the loop by calling `getchar` until you read a newline.  Also, keep in mind that `fgets` includes the newline in the string it reads.